# wxMkdir on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, wxwidgets

I try to use [wxMkdir](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_filefunctions.html#wxmkdir) function to create a new directory in my c++ program. The directory 
`/home/test/Documents/MATLAB/mydata/demo` already exists. But the following code

```
wxString dataDirectory = wxT("/home/test/Documents/MATLAB/mydata/demo/A");

if(! wxDirExists(dataDirectory))
{
    wxMkdir(dataDirectory); 

}
```

will pop up a runtime error dialog saying that

> Directory '/home/test/Documents/MATLAB/mydata/demo/A' couldn't be created (error2: No such file or directory)

and the directory `A` under directory `demo` will not be created. However, if I change the desired directory to `/home/test/Documents/MATLAB/mydata/A`, everything works.

So is there a maximum directory depth for [wxMkdir](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_filefunctions.html#wxmkdir) in the Ubuntu implementation of wxWidgets? This problem is not seen under Mac, however. I searched the web and couldn't get anything meaningful. Anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `mkdir` fails with a "No such file or directory" error, it usually means that the parent directory doesn't exist (or is a dangling symlink). Presumably the same would apply to `wxMkdir`.

Does `/home/test/Documents/MATLAB/mydata/demo` already exist? And just to be sure, is it a directory?

<strike>(If that's not the problem, I'll delete this answer and add it as a comment.)</strike>

Comment: Keith, you are absolutely right. I just checked and found out that the `demo` directory is actually `Demo` directory. No wonder it didn't work. Thanks!